# Use of the protection object in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, spreadsheet-protection

Is there any way to store the `.protection` object in VBA and use it to protect the sheet again with the parameters stored in the object?

I know it is possible to store the object but I can't use it to protect the sheet again.

I need this because different sheets have different protection profiles and I want to use this in a loop.

```
Set wsp = workbookname.Sheets(sheetname).Protection
```

and to protect the sheet again, I would like to use something like this:

```
workbookname.Sheets(sheetname).Protect wsp
```

Comment: I don't think there is. you'll have to resort to `Select Case` or `If` statements to get to protect different sheets in a workbook in different ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could e.g. create s class for each of your profiles with settings, example. HTH

```
' Class module SomeProtectionProfile

Private m_password As Variant
Private m_drawingObjects As Variant
Private m_contents As Variant
Private m_scenarios As Variant
Private m_userInterfaceOnly As Variant
Private m_allowFormattingCells As Variant
Private m_allowFormattingColumns As Variant
Private m_allowFormattingRows As Variant
Private m_allowInsertingColumns As Variant
Private m_allowInsertingRows As Variant
Private m_allowInsertingHyperlinks As Variant
Private m_allowDeletingColumns As Variant
Private m_allowDeletingRows As Variant
Private m_allowSorting As Variant
Private m_allowFiltering As Variant
Private m_allowUsingPivotTables As Variant

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    m_password = "SomePsw1"
    ' and others like m_drawingObjects, m_contents ...
End Sub

Public Sub Protect(sheetToProtect As Worksheet)
    sheetToProtect.Protect Password:=m_password ' , ... and others
End Sub

' Standard module

Sub main()
    With New SomeProtectionProfile
        .Protect workbookname.Sheets(sheetname)
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Ok this pointed me in the right direction. Thanks.
Is there some way to get the state of drawingobjects, scenarios and contents?

Comment: It should be Worksheet.ProtectContents, ProtectScenarios and ProtectDrawingObjects read-only properties. Btw if you like the answer mark it as accepted ... i will be happy about the points :-)